# How do I cut this string in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, expression

I'm currently working on a script to archive an imageboard.
I'm kinda stuck on making links reference correctly, so I could use some help.

I receive this string:

```
<a href="10028949#p10028949" class="quotelink">&gt;&gt;10028949</a><br><br>who that guy???
```

In said string, I need to alter this part:

```
<a href="10028949#p10028949"
```

to become this:

```
<a href="#p10028949"
```

using PHP.

This part may appear more than once in the string, or might not appear at all.
I'd really appreciate it if you had a code snippet I could use for this purpose.

Thanks in advance!
Kenny

Comment: Are you dealing with just the HTML fragment you show or a full HTML page?

Comment: It's just that fragment - that's the entire string that needs to be altered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: as it'll be said in the comments, using a DOM parser is better to parse HTML.

That being said:

```
"/(<a[^>]*?href=")\d+(#[^"]+")/"
```

replaced by `$1$2`

So...

```
$myString = preg_replace("/(<a[^>]*?href=\")\d+(#[^\"]+\")/", "$1$2", $myString);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
Unfortunately, running it returns this error:
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '\' (T_NS_SEPARATOR) in /www/framework.kenniki.ws/workbench-json/test.php on line 6
Line 6 is your unaltered snippet, otherwise I just added a variable definition for the string ($myString) and an echo on $myString.

Comment: @KennyStraube you have to escape the `"` ;) I forgot to do so sorry. Editing

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<a href="<?php echo strstr($str, '#')?>" class="quotelink">&gt;&gt;10028949</a><br><br>who that guy???
```

Comment: Thanks, but this won't do - I don't have the specific part of the string that you replaced, as it's user generated. I only have the entire snippet.

Comment: hey bro i am not replacing the string.

Answer (score 0):

Although you have the question already answered I invite you to see what would (approximately xD) be the correct approach, parsing it with DOM:

```
$string = '<a href="10028949#p10028949" class="quotelink">&gt;&gt;10028949</a><br><br>who that guy???';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($string);

$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a'); // This stores all the links in an array (actually a nodeList Object)

foreach($links as $link){
    $href = $link->getAttribute('href'); //getting the href

    $cut = strpos($href, '#');
    $new_href =  substr($href, $cut); //cutting the string by the #

    $link->setAttribute('href', $new_href); //setting the good href
}

$body = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0); //selecting everything

$output = $dom->saveHTML($body); //passing it into a string

echo $output;
```

---

The advantages of doing it this way is:

- More organized / Cleaner
- Easier to read by others
- You could for example, have mixed links, and you only want to modify some of them. Using Dom you can actually select certain classes only
- You can change other attributes as well, or the selected tag's siblings, parents, children, etc...

Of course you could achieve the last 2 points with regex as well but it would be a complete mess...